# Why do I get an ImportError for opencv2 when I run on python3.7.3?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, opencv

I'm trying to import opencv2 using python3.7.3 on Mac OS 10.10 but an ImportError occurs. How should I solve it?

I tried to install opencv3 using pip, pip3, and homebrew. Probably not install right.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys
import pytesseract as py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/wujian/Desktop/Project/Proj.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.22.100.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.22.100.dylib
```

Comment: Can you show me entire error log?

Comment: That's all I have on python. It says syntax error: invalid syntax on terminal.

Comment: Which version of OpenCV and opencv-python did you install?

Comment: I tried opencv 2.4.13.6 and 3.4.6 and python is 3.7.3

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be (oddly) related to your copy of **libavutil** which is part of **ffmpeg**.

It's hinted at by this part of the error message:

```
ImportError: dlopen(/.../cv2/cv2.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _clock_gettime
  Referenced from: /...python3.7/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/libavutil.56.22.100.dylib (which was built for Mac OS X 10.12)
```

Installing **OpenCV** requires **ffmpeg**. If you installed it [via homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/opencv), it's listed as a dependency.

```
$ brew info opencv
...
==> Dependencies
Build: cmake ✓, pkg-config ✓
Required: eigen ✓, ffmpeg ✓, glog ✓, ...
```

Installing **ffmpeg** will include the **libavutil** library, which can be checked [by downloading pre-built shared libraries](https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/) or [by Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ffmpeg):

```
$ brew list ffmpeg | grep libavutil.*dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.4_1/lib/libavutil.56.22.100.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.4_1/lib/libavutil.56.dylib
/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.4_1/lib/libavutil.dylib
```

Now, your problem is that the **libavutil** (and **ffmpeg**) on your system is not backwards-compatible with your Mac 10.10. It was built targeting a newer Mac 10.12, which seems to have introduced changes to the `clock_gettime` API, causing the "*Symbol not found*" error. This has also been reported to the [opencv-python issues](https://github.com/skvark/opencv-python/issues/67):

> This is not related to OpenCV. The error comes from libavutil
>   (=FFmpeg) which is installed via homebrew. The error is related to
>   binary backward compatibility (apparently Apple has changed the
>   libsystem interface). I'm not too familiar with Apples ecosystem but
>   building FFmpeg against earlier OS version might fix the issue if the
>   older symbols are present also in the latest OS versions. Full
>   backward compatibility on macOS might be impossible to achieve.
>
> ---
>
> I was just bitten by this issue the hard way deep in nested
>   dependencies; FFmpeg targets 10.12 but I'm on 10.11. Hoping for a
>   fixed release soon.
>
> Note that while downgrading Xcode may work too, the proper way to
>   target an earlier version of macOS is to add e.g.
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.11 or -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 to CFLAGS/CXXFLAGS/LDFLAGS; this will tune headers, compiler and linker
>   to produce a binary that is compatible with at least that version of
>   macOS.

The only solution it seems, is to install an older version of **ffmpeg** (with **libavutil**) that is compatible with your Mac 10.10, and then tell OpenCV to link to that older version. You'll probably need to also build OpenCV from source (see [Configure and Build OpenCV to Custom FFMPEG Install](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12427928/2745495)).

You can also try checking this post over at SuperUser:
[Which ffmpeg package I should download for macOS?](https://superuser.com/q/1313069/950877)

- Try installing the older [ffmpeg@2.8](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/ffmpeg@2.8) from Homebrew (though I'm not sure if that's going to work, I don't have a Mac 10.10 to test it on).
- Try downloading pre-built static/shared builds from [ffmpeg.org](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html).
- Try building it from source (see [CompilationGuide/macOS](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/macOS))