# I have run into an error using OpenCV and python

Tags: python, macos, homebrew, opencv

I used to never have any problems with opencv but suddenly even doing the most basic program like displaying an image i get a very long error message immediately.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/Desktop/opencv_test_main/opencv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/python-3.10/cv2.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libswresample.4.dylib
  Referenced from: <D8B40CEE-FD64-33D7-9FBB-D99C076CAE66> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2.reinstall/lib/libavcodec.59.37.100.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib
  Referenced from: <D8E78893-F144-3845-A719-8CFFB8415DC1> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2.reinstall/lib/libavformat.59.27.100.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavutil.57.dylib
  Referenced from: <13009670-C126-334B-9BAE-6C052B28BDCE> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2.reinstall/lib/libswscale.6.7.100.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
myusername@Zachs-MBP-2 opencv_test_main % /opt/homebrew/bin/python3 /Users/myusername/Desktop/opencv_test_main/opencv_test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/Desktop/opencv_test_main/opencv_test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 181, in <module>
    bootstrap()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 153, in bootstrap
    native_module = importlib.import_module("cv2")
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages/cv2/python-3.10/cv2.cpython-310-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libswresample.4.dylib
  Referenced from: <D8B40CEE-FD64-33D7-9FBB-D99C076CAE66> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2.reinstall/lib/libavcodec.59.37.100.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libswresample.4.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib
  Referenced from: <D8E78893-F144-3845-A719-8CFFB8415DC1> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2.reinstall/lib/libavformat.59.27.100.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavcodec.59.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavutil.57.dylib
  Referenced from: <13009670-C126-334B-9BAE-6C052B28BDCE> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2.reinstall/lib/libswscale.6.7.100.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.1.2/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libavutil.57.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling opencv

Comment: If you cannot import cv2, then perhaps your OpenCV is corrupt. I suggest you re-install.

Comment: [tour], [ask], [mre]. question titles should be more descriptive than "I have an error".

Comment: it's complaining about not finding **ffmpeg** libraries. this probably happened to someone else before.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get an ImportError for opencv2 when I run on python3.7.3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57069542/why-do-i-get-an-importerror-for-opencv2-when-i-run-on-python3-7-3)